# Slow JavaScript Performance with JSON request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have an ajax request written in Vanilla JavaScript that gets a JSON file from the server. But this is performing poorly. Here is my code:

```
var data = {
  "Description1": {
    "key1": "Value 1 here",
    "key2": "Value 2 here",
    "key3": "Value 3 here"
  },
  "Description2": {
    "key1": "Value 1 here",
    "key2": "Value 2 here",
    "key3": "Value 3 here"
  }
}

var table = document.querySelector('table');
var options = document.getElementById('option1Id');


var rows = '';
for (var p in data) {
  for (var k in data[p]) {
    if(options.selectedValue == 'Description1'){
    rows += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td><td>' + data[p][k] + '</td></tr>'
   }
   else if(options.selectedValue == 'Description2'){
     rows += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td><td>' + data[p][k] + '</td></tr>'
   }
  }
}
table.innerHTML = rows;
```

HTML Snippet:

```
 <table></table>
    <select id="dropdown" onchange="getJson()">
      <option value="description1">Description1</option>
      <option value="description2">Description2</option>
   </select>
```

The JSON is populating a table, and each time a different option is selected from the dropdown, the data from the table changes. However, this takes about 10 seconds or more to load, and there are less than 100 key/value pairs in the JSON file. Sometimes it won't load at all, and sometimes, when I change values in the drop down, it lags. It's slow. Is there anything I could do to make this code faster? Any suggestions to make this perform better would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing in there that should be causing performance issue, at least, to the extent that you describe. Have you checked how long it takes for the network request to complete?

Comment: Using an array & `.join('')` instead of concatenation will boost perf.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: The rule of thumb of performance optimisation: before trying **ANYTHING** use profiler and find the exact reason of it being slow. Anything you do before you profile - makes no sense.

Comment: @SLaks "will boost perf" --- for an array of 100 elements?

Comment: @zerkms: I didn't say how much.

Comment: @SLaks think for a second: beginners will read your statement, will check that you have a 500k+ rep profile and think "this guy cannot be wrong - let's trust them". Any optimisation attempts *before* profiling are harmful, even the most naive one.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. I will profile and edit my post to state my findings.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```js
 var rows='';
    d1=data.Description1
    d2=data.Description2
    for (var k in d1[p]) {        
        rows += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td><td>' + data[p][k] + '</td></tr>'
       }

    for (var k in d2[p]) {        
        rows += '<tr><td>' + k + '</td><td>' + data[p][k] + '</td></tr>'
       }

//multiple for combined with if statement affect the speed
```